# Allowing to pass an array in DeviseTokenAuth strong params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am having an issue with strong params, passing an array in Devise Token Auth gem [LINK](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth)

```
# ERROR
Unpermitted parameters: options
```

Configure Permitted Params

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << [:username, options: []]
end


# also added in User.rb file
attr_accessor :options
```

I have tried many options, but its not allowing me to pass a data in array.

Is there any solutions ?

Thank You!

Comment: Which rails version using 4?

Comment: @DineshSaini Rails 4.2.5

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example that will help you to setup the parameters:

```
  # You can put the params you want to permit in the empty array.
  def configure_sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up).push(:first_name, :last_name, :arr_options)
  end
```

In your model:

```
class User
  attr_accessor :arr_options

  def initialize
    self.arr_options = []
  end
end
```

Comment: but, I am passing a data as array )))

Comment: Direct array pass is not possible so better first assign the array to another parameter. Let me allow few minutes to do it for you otherwise.

Comment: Also i think, i know what i am doing wrong. Ill test it tomorrow. and post the answer here. I am just passing data as i want in params but that devise `super` tries to save it so all i need to get that my `options params` then delete it, then let devise save his own params. ITS array of objects

Comment: thx, ill do it tomorrow. would be great to see how i can customize devise controller for sign_up. devise provides `def create super end` only.

Comment: ok, and do not forget to mention in route if you override the fn

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109217/discussion-between-dinesh-saini-and-7urkm3n).